# jquery change() not accepting selectors

Tags: jquery, html-select

Ultimately I am trying to run some code which depends on the value (or data stored in any attribute, like `rel`, etc.) of a `select`'s `option`, when that `option` gets selected. I have the following code:

JavaScript:

```
$('select#select1').change(function () {
  set = $('#select1 option:selected').val();
  alert(set);
  // $('#select2').html()
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="select1">
  <option value="1" rel="1">First</option>
  <option value="2" rel="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3" rel="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4" rel="4" selected="selected">Fourth</option>
</select>
```

There are actually two problems here. Firstly, the code above does nothing, as the `change` function doesn't seem to recognize the `$('select#select1')` selector on the first line. If I change it to just `$('select')`, it works. But this is no good, as there are several `select` elements on my page and I need to distinguish which one.

Secondly, if I get it working temporarily with `$('select')` (and deleting other select elements on the page) then I always get the value "1" being alerted, no matter which of the 4 options I select.

Same happens if I use `$('#select1 option:selected').attr('rel');` instead.

For the love of God, why?

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/ZyBHe/

Comment: Your code http://jsfiddle.net/skram/3xS9D/2/ works fine in fiddle.

Comment: @SKS - I got it working. Jeez, how stupid. I had the two select elements floated to the right, and I was clicking on the first one (to the left), thinking that it was the first in my code, when of course it is the one furthest to the right. Utter stupidity. I need to go for a walk. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping it inside `$(document).ready(function () {... });` and use `$(this).val()` inside your handler. See below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/3xS9D/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#select1').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi SKS, thanks for your reply. I already have the code wrapped in $(document).ready(function () {... }); I just omitted it for clarity. However I tried exactly what you have there, and nothing happens. I think the subject of 'this' is the #select1 element itself, rather than the child option element? The #select1 element has no 'val' attribute.

Comment: @Inigo `$(this).va()` inside select handler would get you the selected value. That is part of jQuery `.val` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the id selector, no need to specify the tag in the selector if the element has an id.

```
 $('#select1').change(function () {
        var set = $('#select1 option:selected').val();
        alert(set);
        // $('#select2').html()
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fxx3c/